# How to get the height and width of a tooltip dynamically in c++?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

[MSDN link for TTM_GETBUBBLESIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760387(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't have an example, how the lower word and higher word get returned. Didn't get much from Google. Please care to provide an example of it.

Thanks!

Comment: A Tooltip is a window. If you can access the widow, you can retrieve its size.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Yes we can use `GetWindowRect(hwnd, lpRect)` and from that we can figure it out the height and width. But as the document says, it should return the height and width of the tooltip from that message.

Comment: :is your question how to split the return value in two words ?

Comment: I think yes and wants to know from where I would get both values.

Comment: The packed value is returned by GetMessage !

Comment: Please change the tagging: your are asking about MS Windows API (this is C API  actually) which neither relates to C++ nor to MS Visual Studio (this is the IDE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760387(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Returns the width of the tooltip in the low word and the height in the
>   high word if successful.

A "word" in the context of the Win API usually has a size of 16-bit.

You have to use some [bitwise arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) to extract `width` and `height` from the `result` of the message:

```
width  = result & 0xFFFF;   // extract the low word
height = result >> 16;      // extract the high word
```

Alternatively these macros declared in "windows.h" do the same:

```
width  = LOWORD(result); 
height = HIWORD(result);
```